# Is it okay to use 5 INNER JOIN in MySQLi?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have 6 tables:

`employee, contact, educ, employment, work, familybg` eid is the `foreign key` taken from `employee` table. Now am having trouble with displaying the results on one of my web pages, file.php. What am trying to do is to show all the values taken from each of the 6 tables and combine them together with the use of `INNER JOIN` as a relation to the employee_id which bears the name and minimal details of the employees.

See the query(though not the exact column names):

file.php

```
 $sql=mysqli_query($db,"
SELECT cemp.eid
    , cemp.fname
    , cemp.mname
    , cemp.lname
    , cemp.age
    , cemp.gender
    , cemp.birthday
    , cemp.birthplace
    , cemp.citizenship
    , cemp.status
    , cemp.sss
    , cemp.philhealth
    , cemp.tin
    , cemp.height
    , cemp.weight
    , con.address
    , con.province
    , con.postcode
    , con.telno
    , con.mobile
    , ccon.email
    , ccon.alternate
    , ceduc.elem
    , ceduc.egrad
    , ceduc.high
    , ceduc.hgrad
    , ceduc.college
    , ceduc.cgrad
    , cems.position
    , cems.hireDate
    , cems.job_desc
    , cems.basic
    , cems.salary
    , cw.company_name
    , cw.position
    , cw.desc
    , cw.startDate
    , cw.endDate
    , cfam.fatherName
    , cfam.motherName
    , cfam.sibling
    , cfam.spouse
    , cfam.children 
 FROM ch_employee cemp 
INNER 
 JOIN contact ccon 
   ON ccon.eid = 'cemp.eid'
INNER 
 JOIN educ ceduc 
   ON ceduc.eid = 'cemp.eid' 
INNER 
 JOIN employment cems  
   ON cems.eid = 'cemp.eid'
INNER 
 JOIN work cw 
   ON cw.eid = 'cemp.eid'
INNER 
 JOIN family_bg cfam 
   ON cfam.eid = 'cemp.eid' 
WHERE cemp.eid = '$id';
");
```

The result ofcourse was placed under `while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))` and assigned each column to my given variable names. I.G `$name =$row['name'];...etc...etc` for me to make it easy to put the results on a table. Like this:

`<table><tr><td><td><?php echo $name; ?></td></td><tr></table>` That's what I did to other remaining columns, placing them towards the `<table>` tag.

Since I have 6 tables, I created 6 respective `<table>` which bears all the columns for each of the db tables. I'll show you an example:

```
            <table>
            <thead>
            <tr>
            <th><strong>Name:</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Address:</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Contact#:</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Email:</strong></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo $name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $address; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $contact; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $email; ?></td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
```

But everytime I run this code, no results can be displayed. As if I only made a  with empty rows. Now am wondering, is it the way I used the `INNER JOIN` made this attempt unsuccessful or could it be because of my excessive use of `<table>` tag that affects the whole query? Also, I'm being suspicious with mysqli_fetch_assoc() in my situation is it really what I need to be able to display the rows? or perhaps there's another query function for `mysqli` to retrieve rows from the `database` aside from this? And oh, btw, I have tried mysqli_fetch_array() but even that seems not working.

Any ideas?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with using this many inner join statements. You need to enable error reporting on your SQL query to find out what it doesn't like. Furthermore, print that query to the page, and then run it in phpmyadmin/ mysql console, does it work there?

Comment: Nothing wrong in that, But however it'll take a lot of time as your table increases, proportional to: `M*N*O*P*Q` assuming them as number of rows.

Comment: I think the better question is: Is it really meaningful to query for *all* of those fields at once?

Comment: technically you can join a lot of tables.. but there is a cost benefit from "over" normalizing tables... sometimes its not necessary to store data in 5 tables that are all linked but sometimes it is, just depends on the system and what you are connecting.

Comment: While use inner join all the maping should have values oter wise it wont give output. Try to change all `inner join` to `left join` if it give row set then there are mutually exclusive mapping only available.

Comment: thanks @guru it did work in `LEFT JOIN` :)

Comment: You are welcome. I put that as answer. If it really works make it as green answer.

Comment: Those inverted commas MUST be wrong !!?!??!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While use inner join all the maping should have values oter wise it wont give output.

Try to change all `inner join` to `left join` if it give row set then there are mutually exclusive mapping only available.

So your query will be like follows.

```
$sql=mysqli_query($db,"SELECT cemp.eid,cemp.fname,cemp.mname,cemp.lname,cemp.age,cemp.gender,cemp.birthday,cemp.birthplace,
cemp.citizenship,cemp.status,cemp.sss,cemp.philhealth,cemp.tin,cemp.height,cemp.weight,con.address,con.province,
con.postcode,con.telno,con.mobile,ccon.email,ccon.alternate,ceduc.elem,ceduc.egrad,ceduc.high,ceduc.hgrad,ceduc.college,ceduc.cgrad,
cems.position,cems.hireDate,cems.job_desc,cems.basic,cems.salary,cw.company_name,cw.position,cw.desc,cw.startDate,cw.endDate,
cfam.fatherName,cfam.motherName,cfam.sibling,cfam.spouse,cfam.children FROM ch_employee AS cemp 

LEFT JOIN contact AS ccon ON ccon.eid='cemp.eid'
LEFT JOIN educ AS ceduc ON ceduc.eid='cemp.eid' 
LEFT JOIN employment AS cems ON cems.eid='cemp.eid'
LEFT JOIN work AS cw ON cw.eid='cemp.eid'
LEFT JOIN family_bg AS cfam ON cfam.eid='cemp.eid' WHERE cemp.eid='$id'");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you notice each INNER JOIN is dealt with one at a time and in a consistent "JOIN Link" each time. When the first INNER JOIN is done i.e. `ccon.eid=cemp.eid` - it then proceeds to move to the next one `ceduc.eid=cemp.eid` but making sure that one of the tables being joined was the same as the last join (kinda like following the joins one from another).so you can see as the no of tables will increase the time of construction for the required table will also increase.

**NOTE**
:1)in your sql for inner joins do not use `ccon.eid='cemp.eid'`.use `ccon.eid=cemp.eid`.this is the reason you are not getting any row .follow the same for each inner join.

2) for safer side use left join or right join. because in inner join if any record won't match you will get no output.

Comment: i've placed `or die(mysqli_error($db));` after my query and somehow it show some misnamed columns but after fixing it and doing what you suggest [w/c to remove the single quotes from the rest of the INNER JOIN] the actual output only shows the `<table>` adorned with CSS styling but no values/rows are being displayed.

Comment: run your sql in phpmyadmin and see whether qualifying records are there or not.if any problem let me know.